# Не записываются данные в SQlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Введенные данные не записываются в БД. Где ошибка?
[Проект](https://github.com/Yorksik/SQLiteLesson) на гитхаб.

Сам класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String TAG = "Log_d";

dbHelper mDatabaseHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;


Button btnAdd;
Button btnClear;
Button btnRead;
EditText Email;
EditText Name;
TextView textView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "Кнопки определены");


    //так как в классе dbHelp описаны два (три ?) конструктора мы можем воспользоваться одним из них
    //mDatabaseHelper = new dbHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
    mDatabaseHelper = new dbHelper(this);
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "База данных создано только что", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Зашли в онклик");

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            Log.d(TAG, "Нажата кнопка ADD");
            /*if (mSqLiteDatabase.equals(null)){
                mDatabaseHelper = new dbHelper(this);
                mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }*/

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            // Задайте значения для каждого столбца
            values.put(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME, Name.getText().toString());
            values.put(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL, Email.getText().toString());
            // Вставляем данные в таблицу
            mSqLiteDatabase.insert(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME, null, values);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Данные записаны в таблицу!" + Name.getText().toString() + Email.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.d(TAG, "Имя: " + dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME + " Почта: " + dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL);
            Log.d(TAG, "Имя: " + Name.getText().toString() + " Почта: " + Email.getText().toString());
            Name.setText("");
            Email.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.btnRead:
            Log.d(TAG, "Зашли в Read");
            //Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME, new String[]{dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME,
                    //dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            Cursor cursor =mSqLiteDatabase.query(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                boolean bool = cursor.moveToFirst();
                Log.d(TAG," "+bool);
                do {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "ID " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper._ID)) +
                                    ", NAME " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME)) +
                                    ", EMAIl " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "В базе нет данных!");
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;

        case R.id.btnClear:
            mSqLiteDatabase.delete(dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME,null,null);
            Log.d(TAG,"Таблица " + dbHelper.DB_TEBLE_NAME +" удалена!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Обертка

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "MyDB.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_TEBLE_NAME = "Tebel_Name";
    public static final String DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL = "Mail";
    //public static final String DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_Age = "Age";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
        + DB_TEBLE_NAME + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME
        + " text not null, " + DB_TEBLE_NAME_COLUMN_EMAIL + " text);";



    dbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);

    }

    public dbHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }

    public dbHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Запишем в журнал
        Log.w("SQL", "Обновляемся с версии " + oldVersion + " на версию " + newVersion);

        // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DB_TEBLE_NAME);
        // Создаём новую таблицу
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Введите имя"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Введите Ваш Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Read"
    android:id="@+id/btnRead"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editEmail" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnClear" />
```

Comment: В главном классе не выполняется условие if (cursor.moveToFirst())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с гитхаба, и пишет и читает. Удалите приложение с устройства и установите заново. Если делали изменения в базе и не выполняли `upgrade` версии или не удаляли приложения для пересоздания базы, такие ошибки возникают.

Comment: Спасибо. не знал что при апгрейде приложения через студию оно не удаляется а апгрейдится.

Comment: // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DB_TEBLE_NAME);
        // Создаём новую таблицу
        onCreate(db);

Comment: Этот код должен ведь обновлять базу.

Comment: Чтобы сработал onUpgrade, Вам нужно увеличить версию в перменной DB_VERSION

Comment: Благодарю. Если Вы знаете где можно почитать подробнее и посмотреть правильные реализации работы с БД, пожалуйста напишите.

Comment: Когда я ее изучал, я читал различные блоги, Александра Климова и СтартАндройд. Естественно там только азы, а дальше работала мотивация и в большей степени я люблю экспериментировать. Но в основном естественно читал официальные документации к Android SDK=)